# am I setting the schema wrongly?

Tags: graphql

am I setting the schema wrongly? I can mutation & Query in playground, but in the frontend hit this error: **"Network error: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"**, then I checked in backend, that shows below message, may anyone help me?

```
# import * from './generated/prisma.graphql'

    type Mutation{
        createLeague(name: String, zhName: String, image: String, season: String, nation: String, clubs: Club): League!
        createClub(name: String, zhName: String, tla: String, badge: String, leagues: League): Club!

    }

    type Query{
        leagues: [League]!
        clubs: [Club]!
    }
```

> ```
> Error: The type of Mutation.createLeague(clubs:) must be Input Type but got: Club.
>
> The type of Mutation.createClub(leagues:) must be Input Type but got: League.
>     at assertValidSchema (/mnt/c/Users/chisi/coding/tipson0.1/server/node_modules/graphql/type/validate.js:78:11)
>     at Object.validate (/mnt/c/Users/chisi/coding/tipson0.1/server/node_modules/graphql/validation/validate.js:55:35)
>     at doRunQuery (/mnt/c/Users/chisi/coding/tipson0.1/server/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/runQuery.js:111:42)
>     at /mnt/c/Users/chisi/coding/tipson0.1/server/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/runQuery.js:21:56
>     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
> Error: The type of Mutation.createLeague(clubs:) must be Input Type but got: Club.
>
> The type of Mutation.createClub(leagues:) must be Input Type but got: League.
>     at assertValidSchema (/mnt/c/Users/chisi/coding/tipson0.1/server/node_modules/graphql/type/validate.js:78:11)
>     at Object.validate (/mnt/c/Users/chisi/coding/tipson0.1/server/node_modules/graphql/validation/validate.js:55:35)
>     at doRunQuery (/mnt/c/Users/chisi/coding/tipson0.1/server/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/runQuery.js:111:42)
>     at /mnt/c/Users/chisi/coding/tipson0.1/server/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/runQuery.js:21:56
>     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
> ```

Comment: You need to define an Input type for Club and League and pass it to your mutations. like ClubInput & LeageInput more info: https://graphql.org/graphql-js/mutations-and-input-types/

Comment: As the error indicates, only input types can be used for arguments, not object types. This is a duplicate. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54119116), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46158288), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52744900) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54119116).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apollo / GraphQl - Type must be Input type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52744900/apollo-graphql-type-must-be-input-type)

Comment: thanks all, I got it, I change the type to input ||  import all the thing from Prisma and set the argument as same as the generated file, this two solutions both can solve the issue